# Exportar DataTable a Excel (Con hipervínculo en una celda)

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, mvc, datatables

el problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una aplicación web en la que a través de un botón descargo un reporte en excel, todo funciona perfectamente salvo porque el dato de una columna debe ser un hipervínculo que muestra una imagen, intente lo siguiente...

En SQL-SERVER tengo un STORE PROCEDURE

```
SELECT Guia.NoFolio, OSitio.Nombre AS Origen, OIATA.IATA AS OEntidad,
DSitio.Nombre AS Destino, DIATA.IATA AS DEntidad, TipoTracking.Nombre
AS TipoTrack, CONCAT(Usuario.Nombre, CHAR(32), Usuario.Apellidos) AS Mensajero,
GuiaTracking.Sitio, GuiaTracking.Responsable, GuiaTracking.Observacion,
GuiaTracking.Fecha, (CASE WHEN GuiaTracking.Fotografia <> 'DefaultImage.png'
THEN CONCAT('=HIPERVINCULO("', 'http://[URL por seguridad se omite]/Contenido/files/', GuiaTracking.Fotografia, '","Abrir")')
ELSE 'No Adjunto' END) AS Evidencia
FROM GuiaTracking
INNER JOIN Guia
ON GuiaTracking.Guiaid = Guia.Id
INNER JOIN ClienteSitio AS OSitio
ON Guia.OsitioId = OSitio.Id
INNER JOIN TipoIATA AS OIATA
ON OSitio.TipoIATAId = OIATA.Id
INNER JOIN ClienteSitio AS DSitio
ON Guia.DSitioId = DSitio.Id
INNER JOIN TipoIATA AS DIATA
ON DSitio.TipoIATAId = DIATA.Id
INNER JOIN TipoTracking
ON GuiaTracking.TipoTrackId = TipoTracking.Id
INNER JOIN Usuario
ON GuiaTracking.MUsuarioId = Usuario.Id
WHERE GuiaTracking.GuiaId = @GuiaId
```

Como se aprecia, estoy tratando de insertar el hipervínculo con un string pero con la estructura de una formula de excel

En mi CONTROLLER simplemente vacío la información en un DATATABLE para exportarlo a Excel

```
DataTable ReporteGuias = new DataTable();
            AlbatrosDB conn = new AlbatrosDB();

            conn.InitConn("ReporteTrackingLista");
            conn.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuiaId", GuiaId);

            conn.DataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(conn.Command);
            conn.DataAdapter.Fill(ReporteGuias);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "Tracking_Guia.xlsx");
            XLWorkbook XlLibro = new XLWorkbook();
            XlLibro.Worksheets.Add(ReporteGuias, "Tracking Guía");
            MemoryStream XlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            XlLibro.SaveAs(XlMemoryStream);
            XlMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return View();
```

El problema es que cuando abro el archivo de Excel, resulta que la formula se muestra como si fuera texto plano en vez de mostrarme el hipervínculo para solo dar clic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que hacer para mostrar correctamente el vinculo o que otra alternativa pueda aplicar, espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias.

Comment: probando en excel, solo poniendo la url cruda excel lo autoformatea como url clicleable., solo pon la url cruda.

Comment: Aun colocando la URL sola, vaciándola desde el DATATABLE la muestra como texto plano y no como hipervínculo, pero si, será la mejor solución.